# Trouble Activating SSL on Google App Engine with Custom Domain via Square Space DNS Settings

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, squarespace

I'm attempting to map a custom domain and activate an SSL certificate for a Google App Engine project, using Square Space as my DNS registrar. Despite following Google App Engine's instructions for custom domain mapping, the SSL certificate fails to activate, and I receive the error "DNS records could not be found. Certificate activation will retry automatically."

I've attached screenshots of my current settings on both the Google Cloud Platform and Square Space. On the Google Cloud side, I have the custom domain set up with the suggested DNS records, including A, AAAA, and CNAME records. On the Square Space side, I've input these records exactly as instructed.
[App Engine Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDZlP.png)
[Square Space Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmala.png)

The SSL certificate doesn't seem to activate. I have already tried redoing the process based on Google's documentation twice, but the issue persists.

Has anyone faced a similar issue, and can you provide guidance on what might be going wrong? Any insights on how to properly configure DNS records in Square Space for Google App Engine would be greatly appreciated.

This are the default name server settings. I found under advanced settings on Square Space.

```
Default name server settings:
    dns1.p07.nsone.net
    dns2.p07.nsone.net
    dns3.p07.nsone.net
    dns4.p07.nsone.net
    ns01.squarespacedns.com
    ns02.squarespacedns.com
    ns03.squarespacedns.com
    ns04.squarespacedns.com
```

Comment: Check the settings at your domain's registrar. The registrar settings for `japaintingpr.com` are not set up correctly or they point to the wrong DNS Name Servers.

Comment: I checked the Square Space documentation for pointing a domain, I think set them up correctly. At least I haven't identified the issue. If you have any specific recommendations on how I should change the settings. Please let me know.

Comment: I emailed Square Space this was there reply::                                                              
"Hi there,
 
My name is -----. Thanks for reaching out.
 
I can confirm that the records are added correctly.  
 
Since your domain is pointing away from Squarespace, please contact your website host about the SSL certificate issues you are experiencing."                                        
                                                                                                                                     
So it seems it is correct on Square Space end

Comment: What are the settings at the registrar? Edit your post with details, do not use comments. The key places are the Name Servers at the registrar which point to your DNS servers. If those are wrong, nothing will work as you expect.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not allow me to post images, because I'm new. However I posted a link "Square Space Settings Image" There you can see image of my settings on square space. Anyways thank you for your help.

Comment: Do not post images. You should copy and paste the text into your post. Neither of your images shows the Name Server settings.

Comment: So I need to change the name server settings? I included the name server settings default to the post.

Comment: Your Name Server settings are incorrect. Why do you have two different sets of servers?

Comment: Does are the Square Space defaults.

Comment: They are wrong as I have mentioned. Most likely you need to remove the  `p07.nsone.net` entries, but you have not shown what DNS servers you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the help and patience. I got tired and just bought a new domain at name cheap. It worked at first try. I bought the original domain through square space because they acquired google domains. And I thought they would the most hassle free option. Guess I was wrong. Anyways, again thanks for the help. Happy new year!!